# Running a command in an ansible-playbook from the ansible host using variables from the current ansible process

Tags: ansible

Having hit a brick wall with troubleshooting why one shell script is hanging when I'm trying to run it via Ansible on the remote host, I've discovered that if I run it in an ssh session from the ansible host it executes successfully.

I now want to build that into a playbook as follows:

```
- name: Run script
  local_action: shell ssh $TARGET "/home/ansibler/script.sh"
```

I just need to know how to access the `$TARGET` that this playbook is running on from the selected/limited inventory so I can concatenate it into that `local_action`.

Is there an easy way to access that?

Comment: Do you want to access this environment variable `TARGET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ansible_host`:

```
- name: Run script
  local_action: 'shell ssh {{ ansible_host }} "/home/ansibler/script.sh"'
```